# Django: I want to connect about one-to-many

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.4

Django: I want to connect about one-to-many...

[image]

What should I do?

```
from django.db import models

class Note(models.Model)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class A(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField(Note) # ...? I don't know...

class B(models.Model)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField(Note) # ...? I don't know...
```

Note model : A model = 1 : N...
Note model : B model = 1 : N...

I want to connect Note - A at the same time Note - B...

Please answer me!

Thank you!

Edit 130208 8:36 KST----

Maybe ForegienKey is available...

But my case can't use that.

Because if I want only connection(ex. Note to A), I can do it like the code below.

```
from django.db import models

class Note(models.Model)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    conn = models.ForeignKey(A)

class A(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

But my case need two connection(Note - A, Note - B).

So.... I don't know what should I do...

Comment: I think that your graph contradicts your explanation... The N and the 1 in those links should be swapped if you want the models A and B to have several notes.

Comment: Sorry, you are right...

Comment: I find out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey....

But still I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [models.ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

If you want several notes for each instance of A and B you could try something like this:

```
from django.db import models

    class Note(models.Model):
        content = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        related_to = models.ForeignKey(A_or_B)

    class A_or_B(models.Model):
        pass

    class A(A_or_B):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        addr = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class B(A_or_B):
        nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

searching the notes that belong to a particular A or B intance would be like this:

```
a = A(name="some_name", addr="somewhere")
a.save()
a_note = Note(content="blablabla", related_to=a.id)
a_note.save()
notes_related_to_a = Note.objects.filter(related_to=a.id)
links_from_notes_to_a = {note_x.related_to.a for note_x in notes_related_to_a}
if len(links_from_notes_to_a) and links_from_notes_to_a[0] == a:
    print "It works!"
```

the  `related_to` attribute of the abstract parent class will have an attribute whose name is the uncapitalized name of the actual class of instance (a or b in this example). This attribute contains the instance of `A` or `B` from where you can access the right attributes.

Check [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) of the documentation for more info.

Comment: How to add new Note object?

Comment: @chobo just added how to add it

Answer (score 0):

Use [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

```
from django.db import models

class Note(models.Model)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class A(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    notes = models.ForeignKey(Note) # ...? I don't know...

class B(models.Model)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    notes = models.ForeignKey(Note) # ...? I don't know...
```